# What to incorporate?

Tags: brahmins, enlightenment

In my mind, two of the ways to achieve enlightenment are to get rid of sensory pleasures and Sandhyavandanam; what else is required?

Comment: Sandhya vandanam is not meditating

Comment: Always speak truth in all conditions. Lying, deception and shrewdness are traits of Tamsik demons and evil entities that rule the current age of ignorance Kaliyuga, hence there are theft, violence, hatred and miseries all over earth and people are living worse than animals. Just because something is followed by majority, does not mean it has to be correct. Satyuga and in Satyaloka/Brahmloka, where everyone is enlightened and follow their Dharma, everyone speaks truth and pursues truth and is established in truth/Satya because truth alone is immortal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Tat_Sat

Answer (score 1):

To get an understanding of how one can become realized the best guide is Bhagwat Gita.
So you might wanna start on that a bit.

On the other hand, as per my understanding of Gita (very limited understanding), there are 3 categories to it that are: **Karm-Yog, Bhakti-Yog, and Sankhya-Yog**.
These are not totally mutually exclusive, but more intertwined within each other.

1. **Karm-Yog** suggests that one should follow his karm (responsibilities and duties) with full devotion.
2. **Bhakti-Yog** suggests that one should have an utter devotion to God.
3. **Sankhya-Yog** reveals proper expression of the knowledge of the Supreme Self. (God is within you as Atma).

For details please refer to these answers given by more realized people than I am.
[here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29315/15734), [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34556/15734), [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24481/15734), and definitely [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36217/15734)